# Pure-CSS slide viewer

Tags: css, html5

Not long ago I designed a pure-CSS slide viewer. A demo is available [here](https://madmurphy.github.io/takefive.css/), while the source code can be retrieved [here](https://github.com/madmurphy/takefive.css/) .

I would like to receive opinions, suggestions, and critiques, especially about my choice of designing the CSS selectors focusing on the semantic aspects of HTML5.

Below the main CSS:

```css
/*\
|*|
|*|         :: Take five! ::
|*|
|*|
|*| A semantically-consistent pure-CSS slide renderer
|*|
|*| https://github.com/madmurphy/takefive.css/
|*|
|*| Version 1.2.6
|*|
|*| (c) madmurphy
|*|
|*| This CSS is released under the GNU Public License, version 3 or later.
|*| http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
|*|
|*|
\*/


@font-face {
/*
    :: The font used by Take five! ::
*/
    font-family: "report";
    src: url("fonts/1942-report/webfont.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/1942-report/webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/1942-report/webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/1942-report/webfont.svg") format("svg");
}

/*\
|*|
|*| The viewport
|*|
\*/

article.slide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 67px 12px 50px 83%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: report, courier, monospace;
    font-size: .75em;
    z-index: 11109;
    transition: visibility 0s .5s, opacity .5s linear;
}

article.slide:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

/*\
|*|
|*| An aimated hashtag at the right-bottom corner...
|*|
\*/

article.slide[data-context]::before,
article.slide:not(.no-hashtag)::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -80px;  /* -6.35em */
    margin: .95em;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    transition: 1s bottom;
    max-width: calc(50% - 87px);
}

article.slide[data-context]:target::before,
article.slide:not(.no-hashtag):target::after {
    bottom: 0;
}

article.slide:not(.no-hashtag)::after {
    content: "hashtag: #" attr(id);
    right: 0;
}

article.slide[data-context]::before {
    content: attr(data-context);
    left: 0;
}

/*\
|*|
|*| General elements
|*|
\*/

article.slide a[href], 
article.slide a[href]:hover,
article.slide a[href]:active,
article.slide a[href]:visited {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

article.slide hr {
    width: 40%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 12px auto;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*\
|*|
|*| HTML5 semantic children
|*|
\*/

/*

Search of the first *semantically valid* element to be centered in the slide,
i.e.: `:not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside)`, a.k.a. "the <leeloo> element".

START {

*/

article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) {
/*
    :: Whatever you set here, unless you want differently, please
       restore it in the unset place `@leeloo_itself`! ::
*/
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Vertically centering; solution found at: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#viewport3 */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto -50% auto auto;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* Ease in/out... */
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 11115;
    font-size: 1px;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out, .5s max-height ease, .3s font-size linear;
}

article.slide:target > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) {
/*
    :: Whatever you set here, unless you want differently, please
       restore it in the unset place `@leeloo_ease_in_out`! ::
*/
    /* Ease in-out... */
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 50%;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* We want just the first one: unset the others. */

article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) {
/*
    --> unset place: `@leeloo_itself`
*/
    box-sizing: initial;
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    margin: initial;
    max-height: initial;
    max-width: initial;
    overflow: initial;
    font-size: inherit;
    transition: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

article.slide:target > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) {
/*
    --> unset place: `@leeloo_ease_in_out`
*/
    max-height: initial;
    max-width: initial;
    /* Kept values: font-size */
}

/* All direct children but <leeloo> */

article.slide > nav:not(:first-of-type),
article.slide > header:not(:first-of-type),
article.slide > footer:not(:first-of-type),
article.slide > aside:not(:first-of-type),
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11114;
}

/*

} END

*/

/* One <nav>, if present */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 90px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 17%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 12px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* One <header>, if present */

article.slide > header:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 50px;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    font-size: larger;
    z-index: 11110;     /* the header is always *under* the clickable layer */
}

/* One <footer>, if present */

article.slide > footer:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;       /* see article.slide.padding-bottom for this */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 17%;     /* see article.slide.padding-right for this */
    text-align: right;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 11113;
}

/* One <aside>, if present */

article.slide > aside:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;       /* see article.slide.padding-bottom for this */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 17%;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 12px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 11112;
}

/*\
|*|
|*| HTML5 semantic sub-children
|*|
\*/

/* Navigation links */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href] {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: normal;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]) {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border: 2px #ffffff dashed;
    margin: 16px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 11116;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color .5s linear;
    text-align: center;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]):first-child,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:first-child + a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]) {
    margin-top: 0;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]) + a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"]),
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]) + a[href][rel~="parent"] + a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"]) {
    margin-top: 14px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]):hover {
    background-color: rgba(184,205,226,.09);
}

    /*****************************************

    :: Special links: the `a[href][rel~="parent"]` link ::

    THE RULE IS THE FOLLOWING:

    (Cond. 1.) If `a[href][rel~="parent"]` is inside the main <nav>:

        --> it will be shown on the right-top corner; a transparent, clickable, full-screen
            layer will be created.

    (Cond. 2.) If `a[href][rel~="parent"]` is inside the <leeloo> element and is *empty*:

        --> a transparent clickable layer will cover the whole (and only) <leeloo> element.

    (Cond. 3.) If `a[href][rel~="parent"]` is inside the <leeloo> element but is *not empty*,
    (Cond. 4.) or if `a[href][rel~="parent"]` is outside both the main <nav> and the <leeloo> element (empty or not empty),
    (Cond. 5.) or if `a[href][rel~="parent"]` *is* <leeloo> itself:

        --> it will be ignored by this CSS and displayed as a normal link.

    *****************************************/

/* (Cond. 1.) */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:not(.no-nav) {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px 56px 16px 16px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 11111;
    transition: 1s color;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:not(.no-nav):hover {
    color: inherit;
}

/* (Cond. 2.) */

article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) a[href][rel~="parent"]:empty::before {
/*
    :: Whatever you set here, unless you want differently, please
       restore it in the unset place `@leeloo_exit_layer`! ::
*/
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 11118;
}

article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) a[href][rel~="parent"]:empty::before,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) a[href][rel~="parent"]:empty ~ a[href][rel~="parent"]:empty::before {
/*
    --> unset place: `@leeloo_exit_layer`
*/
    content: initial;
    display: initial;
    position: initial;
    top: initial;
    left: initial;
    margin: initial;
    padding: initial;
    width: initial;
    height: initial;
    z-index: initial;
}

/* All links when empty, except `a.no-nav[href][rel~="parent"]` and `a[href][rel~="child"]` */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a.no-nav[href][rel~="parent"]:empty,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"]):empty,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"].no-label:not([rel~="parent"]):empty {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    text-align: initial;
    overflow: initial;
    line-height: initial;
    font-size: initial;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: unset;
    z-index: 11116;
}

/* All links when not empty, except `a.no-nav[href][rel~="parent"]` and `a[href][rel~="child"]` */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a.no-nav[href][rel~="parent"]:not(:empty),
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"]):not(:empty) {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 12px);
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border-top: 2px #ffffff solid;
    border-right: 2px #ffffff solid;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    transition: .5s left;
    z-index: 11116;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

/* <nav> links' "ease in/out" animation */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a.no-nav[href][rel~="parent"]:not(:empty):hover,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"]):not(:empty):hover {
    left: -12px;
}

/* Labels of semantic links */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][data-label]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    /* Here are the properties shared between of ALL the labels of <nav>'s links. */
    /* Remember that `a[href][rel~="parent"]` will be placed on the top-right corner of the viewport. */
    display: block;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel]:not([rel~="child"]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][data-label]:not([rel~="child"]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    text-align: right;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Uncomment the following selector if you want to style the labels of all <nav> links except `a[href][rel~="parent"]` and `a[href][rel~="child"]` */

/*

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"])[rel]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href]:not([rel~="parent"]):not([rel~="child"])[data-label]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    background-color: red;
}

*/

/* Unknown "rel" attributes */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: attr(rel);
    text-transform: capitalize;

}

/* Known "rel" attributes */

article.slide a[href][rel~="tag"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "\2605";
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="tag"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Tagged content";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="author"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Author";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="bookmark"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Share it!";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="first"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "First slide";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="last"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Last slide";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="index"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Index";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="prev"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Previous slide";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="next"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Next slide";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="child"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label)::before {
    content: "More" !important;
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: "Back to:";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label):empty::before {
    content: "Click to exit";
    text-transform: none;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a.no-nav[href][rel~="parent"]:not([data-label]):not(.no-label)::before {
    content: "Back to";
    text-transform: none;
}

/* User-set labels */

article.slide a[href][rel~="tag"][data-label]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][data-label]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    content: attr(data-label) !important;
}

article.slide a[href][rel~="tag"]:not(.no-label):not(:empty)::before {
    margin-right: .3em;
}

/* Buttons generated by "Author" "Bookmark" "First" "Last" "Index" "Prev" "Next" */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="first"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="index"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="last"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="prev"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="next"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="bookmark"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after,
article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="author"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11116;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="author"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "@";
    left: calc(80% - 48px);
    top: initial;
    bottom: 10%;
    font-size: 40px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="bookmark"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\1F517";
    /* try also: `content: "\1F4D1";` */
    /* try also: `content: "#";` */
    left: calc(80% - 48px);
    top: 10%;
    bottom: initial;
    font-size: 40px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="first"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\21E4";
    top: initial;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: calc(50% - 75px);
    font-size: 40px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="last"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\21E5";
    top: initial;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: calc(50% + 27px);
    font-size: 40px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="index"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\2302";
    top: initial;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: calc(50% - 24px);
    font-size: 40px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="prev"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\276E";
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 48px;
}

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="next"]:not([rel~="parent"]):not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\276F";
    left: calc(80% - 48px);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 48px;
}

/* Exit button */

article.slide > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:not(.no-nav)::after {
    content: "\00D7";
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;        /* 1.8em */
    height: 50px;       /* 1.8em */
    line-height: 44px;  /* 1.6em */
    font-size: 28px;    /* 2.3em */
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    top: -80px;     /* -2.88em */
    bottom: initial;
    font-family: serif;
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 11117;
    transition: 1s top;
}

article.slide:target > nav:first-of-type a[href][rel~="parent"]:not(.no-nav)::after {
    top: 0;
}

/*\
|*|
|*| Content
|*|
\*/

/* Multimedia */

article.slide figure {
    text-align: center;
}

article.slide img,
article.slide audio,
article.slide video,
article.slide iframe {
    border: 3px #ffffff solid;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Animation */
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    transition: .5s max-width ease, .5s max-height, ease;
}

article.slide:target img,
article.slide:target audio,
article.slide:target video,
article.slide:target iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* it makes no sense to set the max-height in percentage for sub-children... */
    max-height: 12cm;
}

/* Text content */

article.slide article,
article.slide section {
    overflow: auto !important;
}

article.slide > article,
article.slide > section {
/*
    :: Whatever you set here, unless you want differently, please
       restore it in the unset place `@leeloo_text_content`! ::
*/
    padding: 6px;
}

article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ article,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ section {
/*
    --> unset place: `@leeloo_text_content`
*/
    padding: initial;
}

article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ h1,
article.slide > * h1,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ h2,
article.slide > * h2,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ h3,
article.slide > * h3,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ h4,
article.slide > * h4,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ h5,
article.slide > * h5,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ h6,
article.slide > * h6,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ p,
article.slide > * p,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ ol,
article.slide > * ol,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ ul,
article.slide > * ul {
    margin: .5em 0 !important;
}

article.slide article,
article.slide section,
article.slide h1,
article.slide h2,
article.slide h3,
article.slide h4,
article.slide h5,
article.slide h6,
article.slide p {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

article.slide h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

article.slide h2 {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

article.slide h3 {
    font-size: 1.05em !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

article.slide p {
    text-align: justify;
}

article.slide blockquote {
    color: #afafaf;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0 1.75em !important;

}

article.slide:target > blockquote {
/*
    :: Whatever you set here, unless you want differently, please
       restore it in the unset place `@leeloo_blockquote_content`! ::
*/
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
}

article.slide:target > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ blockquote {
/*
    --> unset place: `@leeloo_blockquote_content`
*/
    font-size: inherit !important;
}

article.slide > * blockquote,
article.slide > :not(nav):not(header):not(footer):not(aside) ~ blockquote {
    margin: 1em .25em !important;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

article.slide blockquote::before,
article.slide blockquote::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: #cccccc;
    width: .75em;
    height: 1em;
}

article.slide blockquote::before {
    content: "\201C";
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

article.slide blockquote::after {
    content: "\201E";
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

article.slide blockquote cite {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 24px;
    font-style: normal;
}

article.slide blockquote cite::before {
    content: "\2014";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
}

article.slide fieldset > legend {
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 6px;
}

article.slide fieldset > legend,
article.slide input,
article.slide textarea,
article.slide select,
article.slide button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px #ffffff solid;
    color: #ffffff;
}

article.slide code {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}


              /**\
             /*  *\
            /*    *\
           /*      *\
          /*        *\
         /*          *\
        /*     :)     *\
       /*              *\
      /*                *\
      |*   END OF CSS   *|
      |*                *|
      |*                *|
    \**********************/
```

And below a basic HTML example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://madmurphy.github.io/takefive.css/css/takefive_min.css" media="screen" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<p><a href="#example-photo-2">Example photo</a></p>

<article class="slide" id="example-photo-2">
    <header>
        <h2>Slide 2 of 10</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="#nowhere" rel="parent">My diary</a>
        <a href="#my-gallery" rel="index">All photos</a>
        <a href="#example-photo-1" rel="prev">Example photo #1</a>
        <a href="#example-photo-3" rel="next">Example photo #3</a>
        <a href="#quotation-example" rel="first">A quotation</a>
        <a href="#audio-example" rel="last">Embedded audio example</a>
        <a href="#example-photo-2" rel="bookmark">Example photo #2</a>
        <a href="mailto:me@example.org" rel="author">John Doe</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/" data-label="Other">Custom link</a>
    </nav>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://madmurphy.github.io/takefive.css/images/2.jpg" />
        <figcaption>Yellow at the lake</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget blandit lacus. Suspendisse feugiat, leo quis hendrerit auctor, nisl urna finibus ante, sit amet dictum orci lorem nec ipsum. Integer nunc tortor, semper in consectetur vitae, luctus vitae sapien. Pellentesque tempus dictum euismod. Maecenas ullamcorper orci felis, nec blandit ante sollicitudin vitae. Integer a tincidunt lacus. Quisque efficitur maximus lacus, nec commodo risus elementum nec.</p>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

> **Note:** All children of the above `<article class="slide">` are optional.

Comment: Any chance of a corresponding small HTML so we can see the document structure it's supposed to work with?  Thanks.

Comment: Opinions? Suggestions? Anyone?